# CSS @keyframes Animation: Scaling up a div does not change the "size of it's box"

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have got a list of `<div>` elements.

I use JavaScript to change the contents of this list by inserting or removing elements according to filters, put in by users.

When inserting/creating a new `<div>` element, I use `@keyframe` animations to change the opacity from `zero` to `one` and give a little fade in from the left.

```css
@keyframes fade-in-left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Everything is working perfectly fine but there is one crucial design problem:

What I want now, is a scale up animation. I can  easily do that but the problem is that when inserting a new element, the elements in the list after it snap to the position at which they would be when the inserted `<div>` has completed scaling to `1`.

The problem here is obviously the following: Changing the scale of a transform does not affect the positioning of the other elements. I would have to change the height. But I cannot do that, there is padding, margin etc.

So can anyone please tell me a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: consider animation max-height from 0 to a big value

Comment: That was the perfectl solution. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: This is not a thing with animation, it's entirely to do with `transform`. `transform`ed elements don't apply their transformation to the document flow, just their original size/position.